# create list array from javascript tree object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have javascript tree object and i want to convert it to list array

My tree:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wahmal/f2pcmptt/)

how to get 'href' value and push it to an array list ?

```
var res=['hrefValue','hrefValue','hrefValue','hrefValue','hrefValue','hrefValue'];
```

Comment: Can you let us know more about your question?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have array list, but it does have Arrays with similar functionality.

Comment: Also why are you trying to wrap this into a single array item and then into a string with `'[{...}]'`? Remove the quotes `'[ .... ]'`, the `'` quote doesn't support multi-line string and there is no reason to do that. It's not supported to be a big string, and will not function right if you have it like that.

Comment: Consider using this library it contains functions to convert from tree data to array and vise versa. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/binary-tree, it has functions like fromArray(), toArray().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function convert(tree){
    return tree.reduce(function(acc, o) {       // check the docs for reducs in the link bellow
        if(o.href)                              // if this object has an href
            acc.push(o.href);                   // add the href to the result array
        if(o.nodes)                             // if this object has children
            acc = acc.concat(convert(o.nodes)); // get their href and add (concat) them to the result
        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

- `tree` should be an array not a string, if you have it as a string (JSON string) then you have to parse it before passing it to the function using `JSON.parse`.
- Javascript doesn't have ArrayLists, it only have arrays.
- Here is the link to the docs of [**Array.prototype.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
- Here is a working [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jaat7hvL/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var getHrefs = function(nodes) {
    return nodes.reduce(function (arr, node) {
        return arr.concat(node.href).concat(node.nodes ? getHrefs(node.nodes) : []);
    }, []);
}

var hrefs = getHrefs(tree);   // ["7400.34.03.00.00.00", "7400.34.03.01.00.00", ... etc.]
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation about your question , code only answers are not so useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()`, spread element

```
let res = [];
tree.map(({href, nodes}) => res = [...res, href, ...nodes.map(({href:h}) => h)]);
// do stuff with `res`
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4ajr1spr/